# How do i redirect to my protected URL once i got the JWT?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, express-jwt

I´m doing a Node Js, Express easy and simple login using JWT for the first time, but i don´t know how to redirection from one route to another, In this image for example, in the /auth route, i make a user verification then i generate an JWT token and make 2 distinctions based on user´s parameters (admin and estado"), then I put in a header the token and send it as a response [the image shows this, and how i put the token in the header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEDUt.png) and the output is this [I see the token and a message in a json on the navegator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBbPT.png)

How do i make to instead showing me this json, it redirect me to /updateUsers route? that route already have a middleware to validate the token but i don´t really know how to go to there from /auth

Comment: Hi, using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Normally on an API the `auth` route only returns the token, by `res.json` or `res.cookie`, if you're using [CookieParser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser).

The `res.headers` is normally used when you want to authenticate to an existing `API`, so, in your case, you should just return the token as a `JSON` or `cookie`, and the Frontend will store it somewhere.

The redirect you want, you should add it in a Middleware, where if:

1. The user has an authenticated token, you use `next()` to continue the normal routing
2. The user hasn't an authenticated token or doesn't have a token, you use `res.redirect()` to a route where you show a message like `Unauthorized` or something like this.

So, basically, you should add this validation on the Middleware you have for authentication(Recommended), or create a new one for that.